# Drawing many points in Python Qt with OpenGL

Tags: python, opengl, pyqt

What is the easiest and most performat way of drawing many points with differrent colors each?

Right now I do the following:

```
paintGL(self):

    ...

    glBegin(GL_POINTS)

    for x, y, z, r, g, b in points:
        glColor(r, g, b)
        glVertex3f(x, y, z)

    glEnd()
```

This gets really slow for ~50k points when drawing them for every frame in paintGL(). I want to be able to rotate and zoom the cloud.

I already saw glDrawElements, glDrawArrays and I also heard about shaders and stuff. Please point me in the right direction.

**UPDATE2:**

I found a way, here it is:

```
def init(self):

    ...

    points = np.array(points, dtype=np.float64)
    colors = np.array(colors, dtype=np.float64)

    self.count = len(points)
    self.vbo_points = VBO(points)
    self.vbo_colors = VBO(colors)

def paintGL(self):

    ...

    self.vbo_points.bind()
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_DOUBLE, 0, self.vbo_points)

    self.vbo_colors.bind()
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY)
    glColorPointer(3, GL_DOUBLE, 0, self.vbo_colors)

    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, self.count)
```

Comment: A big 'ole [VBO](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Buffer_Object) & [`glDrawArrays()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawArrays.xhtml).

Comment: This looks promising, but I'm failing in implementing it. Could u please outline usage with pseudo code?